# Convert Node.js HTTP request to Python

Tags: python, node.js, http-headers, httprequest

I have this small piece of code in node.js, which makes an API request and I need to convert this into python requests.get()....

```
import got from 'got'
got.get(`https://example.com/api`, {
      json: true,
      query: {
        4,
        data: `12345`
      },
})
```

So my python code would start like this:

```
import requests

requests.get('https://example.com/api')
```

But how can I add the parameters

```
      json: true,
      query: {
        4,
        data: `12345`
      },
```

in the python request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend looking at available docs when trying to solve problems like this, you'll get the answer a lot quicker generally and learn a lot more - I have linked the docs within this answer to make it easier to explore them for future use. I have never used the nodejs got library, but looked at the docs to identify what each of the parameters mean, the [npm page has good documentation for this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got):

- [json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got#json) - Sets content type header to "application/json", sets
  accept header to "application/json", and will automatically run
  JSON.parse(response). I am not aware of your familiarity with http
  headers, but more information can be looked up on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) and a list
  of headers can be found on the [wikipedia article for header
  fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields).
- [query](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got#query) - This sets the query string for the request.
  I assume you are familiar with this, but more information can be
  checked on [the wikipedia for query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

So, from the above it looks lke you are trying to send the following request to the server:

- URL (with query string): https://example.com/api?4&data=12345
- Headers

  - type: json/appication
  - accept: json/application

I would recommend reading through the python [requests library user guide](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v1.0.0/#user-guide) to get a better understanding of how to use the library.

For setting custom headers, the [optional "headers" parameter can be used](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v1.0.0/user/quickstart/#custom-headers).

For query string, the [optional "params" parameter allows for this](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v1.0.0/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls). The only problem with params is the lack of support for a valueless key (the 4 in your example), to get around this encoding the query string in the url directly may be the best approach until the requests library supports this feature. Not sure when support will be available, but I did find a [closed issue on GitHub](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/2651) mentioning potential support in a later version.